# sql query with date difference

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/emeYs.png
I need to find all the "CF" that have a Data_Iscrizione older than 5 years.
I've tried this:

```
SELECT U.CF
FROM Utente AS U
WHERE Data_Iscrizione< date_sub(curdate(),interval 5 years)
```

But I get this error:[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9ShP.png)
What I'm missing?

updated foramt

Answer (score 0):

`years` is not plural:

```
SELECT U.CF
FROM Utente U
WHERE Data_Iscrizione < date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 year)
LIMIT 0, 25;
```